# 2D ArrayList Usage

Tags: java, arraylist

I was doing a coding problem that used a 2D ArrayList that contained the following:

```
[["HTML","C#"],
 ["C#","Python"],
 ["Python", "HTML"]]
```

I don't want to go too in depth as to what the question was but essentially I wanted to grab the elements within that 2D ArrayList and insert them into a 1D ArrayList as individual elements. For example if I grabbed:

```
["HTML","C#"]
```

In the 1D ArrayList "HTML" would be the element at index 0 and "C#" the element at index 1. I tried doing this by doing the following:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoD = new ArrayList<>();//2D ArrayList containing the elements above
ArrayList<String> oneD = new ArrayList<String>();
oneD.add(twoD.get(0));
```

That did not work, however this did:

```
ArrayList<String> oneD = twoD.get(0);
```

So I am confused as to why the first approach did not work but the second one did.

Comment: in the first way twoD.get(0) return ArrayList<string> and oneD is ArrayList<string>
so oneD would accept to get String object but your code add ArrayList<string> to it not string you instead can use addAll https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

and for your second way two.get(0) get arraylist<string> and you assign it to the oneD
so it fine in this case

Comment: Your first line attempts to insert a `List<String>` into a `List<String>`, which won't work because it expects to have `String`s inserted. Your second line assigns a reference to a `List<String>` to a reference to a `List<String>`, which does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `java.util.stream` to achieve what you want

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // If using 2D array
    String[][] languages = {{"HTML","CSS"},{"JAVA","C++"},{"Python","ruby"}};
    List<String> languageList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String[] s:languages) {
        for (String lang: s) {
            languageList.add(lang);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n==Print Values in 2D array==");
    languageList.stream().forEach(s-> System.out.println(s));

    //if using 2D arrayList
    List<List<String>> languagesArr = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String[] s:languages) {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String lang: s) {
            temp.add(lang);
        }
        languagesArr.add(temp);
    }
    System.out.println("\n==Print Values 2D ArrayList==");
    languagesArr.stream().forEach(s-> s.stream().forEach(ss-> System.out.println(ss)));
}
```

as you can see in the first for the 2D array which is `languages` array we are adding it to a single-dimensional `arraylist` using `for each and then print values using` stream`. for the next 2D` arraylist`we can literally use`stream`inside another`stream` to print the values.

The final output will be like this.

```
==Print Values in 2D array==
HTML
CSS
JAVA
C++
Python
ruby

==Print Values 2D ArrayList==
HTML
CSS
JAVA
C++
Python
ruby
```